# Load test agent throws: MissingMethodException

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing, distributed

I have set up a load test rig and installed controller on my local machine and agent remotely. That works fine they are connected and communicating.

When I start the test the test completes, with 0 requests sent and finishes in 2 sec (specified 30sec duration). It throws 3 errors from which one is:

"00:00:01   AgentName   DashboardLoadingTest    Dasboard load test    Exception   MissingMethodException  Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTest.get_ResultsLocale()'.  Stack-"

Can someone had similar issue and help me with this?

here is the stack:

> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestCaseContext..ctor(WebTestCaseVariation variation, Int32 webTestIteration, Hashtable runContextParameters, LoadTestContext loadTestContext)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestCaseVariation..ctor(WebTestElement webTestElement, Int32 testIteration, Hashtable runContextParameters, WebTestUserContext userContext, LoadTestContext loadTestContext, Boolean completeRequestOnAbort, Boolean defaultReportingName)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestElement.CreateVariation(IRunContext runContext, Int32 testIteration, WebTestUserContext userContext, LoadTestContext loadTestContext, Boolean completeRequestOnAbort, Boolean defaultReportingName)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.ScenarioEngine.CreateWebTestVariation(LoadTestUserContext userContext, WebTestElement webTestElement, Int32 testIteration)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.ScenarioEngine.CreateVariation(LoadTestUserContext userContext, Boolean isTerminateTest)

Comment: What happens if you run the web test locally? What happens if you run a load test locally (very low load, perhaps one virtual user and two iterations)?

Comment: I tried with 2 agents, the second is on a VM that has VS2015 installed and it's OK, so probably the issue is that I'm missing VS2015 on the first one.
When I run it locally also is OK but I want to run on multiple agents.